# ssh remote command error codes

Tags: ssh

How can i differentitate if the return code ($?) came from the ssh command itssef or from the command to be executed remotely when using the following syntax:

```
ssh user@host "some remote command"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page

> ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred

so anything that's not 255 must have come from the remote command.